# How to reinstall Ubuntu drivers using CD-ROM ISO while I'm offline

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, nvidia

**What I'm stuck at**

- My physical network devices (Wi-Fi and Ethernet) are not available in Kubuntu 22.04 (unavailable in `ip link` and `nmcli device`, available in `lshw -c network`)
- The *additional drivers* tab in `software-properties-qt` is empty, although I've mounted and added the Kubuntu ISO as a repository, disabled online repositories, and did apt clean and update
- Any try to install another alternative kernel to include alternative boot options with drivers included fails because of "no installation candidate" in the ISO file which doesn't have "Release" file.
- It's a failure in a bunch of drivers. Even my touchpad doesn't work anymore.

**How did I manage to cause this mess?**

- I tried to install nvidia proprietary drivers, but the boot was failing.
- I did some Nvidia package removing and `apt clean/autoremove` which apparently has broken my alternative kernels.
- I changed a `2` to `0` in an auto-generated nvidia config to bypass Nvidia card and load Kubuntu using my onboard Intel Graphics card.

**What I think I need**

- I want my network connection back to access online repositories and fix the mess.
- I'd appreciate any hints for after accessing the network.
- I prefer to avoid reinstallation of OS and reconfiguration.

Comment: I don't understand what you're after sorry, but you mention a Kubuntu ISO, so if you've applied any upgrades since your initial install; the ISO won't help you unless you're using the current *jammy daily* & not your installation media. You can also re-install without loss of data or user configs (*I have 3 installs on this box that I never apply upgrades; as a QA or Quality Assurance test, I upgrade my packages via re-install weekly & ensure my manually installed packages got auto-reinstalled, my music & data files were untouched as part of the QA test!*).

Comment: Thanks. Is reinstall possible without loss of "data, user config" **and installed applications**? If so, could you provide a link to the exact procedure? (I've already did bad in trial and error!)

Comment: I've written about it on this site 30+ times, but I have trouble finding answers that have less than 9 upvotes, so I'm not going to look. It's just using Manual Partitioning/Something-else, re-use existing partitions and **not formatting** them (*the lack of format [esp. /] triggers the repair installation*). I've written about it [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) where Lubuntu call it "*Install using existing partition*" though that was written for QA-testers not end-users. It's intended for Ubuntu repository software (not 3rd party)

Comment: ...  As always backup first  (*for starters it's easy to forget the format! as it's the default*), it works with Ubuntu Desktop & all *flavors*, doesn't deal well with server applications (where config files can be stored in system directories which get wiped; desktop apps don't do that as they're in $HOME) and works with current Desktop ISOs using `ubiquity` and `calamares` (*two flavors including Lubuntu use `calamares`). I've not used it successfully with the *canary* installer, but is likely to be added there [in due course] and return to being a Repair Installation menu item like long ago

Comment: Thanks. It succeeded eventually. For the record: It was booting to busybox initramfs prompt with some *"ALERT! UUID=? not found"* message when I entered `exit` there. I did some searching and finally found out that because the kernel version in the installation media (ISO) was behind my latest version, I had to select an older alternative Ubuntu boot option. After that, I did some updates and upgrades in aptitude and all is fine except those packages which I'd installed manually or using snap, which I have to re-install.